# How to get Name on chip or Index of chip?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, event-handling

1) I am using following method to create multiple chips (Material Design). In React

```
<div style={styles.wrapper} className="container">

   {
       arrayName.map((row, index)=>(
       <Chip
         style={styles.chip}
         key={index}
         onTouchTap={handleTouchTap}
       >

         {row.name}
       </Chip>
     ))
   }

 </div>
```

I am not able to get value from event handler by using  "event.target.value"
is there another way to get value on chips?

```
arrayName contains name of programming languages like Angular, React etc.
```

2) can change color of chips based on index I set?

Answer (score 1):

You can `bind` the `index` or `value` directly to `onTouchTap` function, and access the value directly.

**Binding Name:**

```
<div style={styles.wrapper} className="container">
   {
       arrayName.map((row, index)=>(
          <Chip
             style={styles.chip}
             key={index}
             onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap.bind(this, row.name)}
          >    
             {row.name}
          </Chip>
      ))
   }

 </div>

handleTouchTap(name){
   console.log('name:', name);
}
```

**Binding Index:**

```
<div style={styles.wrapper} className="container">
   {
       arrayName.map((row, index)=>(
          <Chip
             style={styles.chip}
             key={index}
             onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap.bind(this, index)}
          >
             {row.name}
          </Chip>
      ))
   }
</div>

handleTouchTap(index){
   console.log('name:', arrayName[index].name);
}
```

**Update**:

To assign different colors to chip, First define the color codes in an To array like this:

```
let colors = ['#color1', '#color2', '#color3', '#color4'....];
```

Then Use `Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);` to pick a random no in the range of `0 to colors.length`, assign that color to chip like this:

```
 style={{backgroundColor: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]}}
```

It will work.

Comment: Thank You for solution,please answer second question how to style above created chip independently?

Comment: what kind of styling you want on the chip, different color for different chip ?

Comment: Different color

Comment: specify all the colors in an array like this: a = ['#color1', '#color2', '#color3'...], then use Math.randm(), to pick a random calor from that array and assign that color to that chip.

Comment: sorry for misleading question, I want change color of chip from "onTouchTap" method

Comment: @AviatorX you don't need to pass the event object it will automatically get passed as second parameter, use this: `handleTouchTap(index, event){console.log('event', event.target)}` it will print the target dom element :)

Comment: Thank You, I got that. I'm not able to get **event.currentTarget** value. It's outputing blank object. can you help with this?